# mod_security: Block only if a client causes more than 10 error messages

Tags: apache, security, mod-security, mod-security2

)

I am currently trying to create a list of whitelists in modsecurity for my application.

To reduce false positives i thought about something like this: If a user causes more than 10 error message (mod security messages) it will be blocked then.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Almost. You haven't specified what kind of error messages, for example, nor if you want 10 in a single request or 10 in a given time period.

There are thresholds you can set in the CRS setup for mod_security that will trigger rejections based on a total score; raising/lowering that threshold will set the level to reject a single request.

If you're looking at 403's or rejections over a time period, you probably want to google "fail2ban mod_security" for ways to set f2b up to read the mod_security log files and put the offending IP in "jail" after enough misbehavior.